# Estimated mining profits are overestimated

Tags: mining-pools, mining

I mine with 1KH/s for moneropool.com. The estimated mining profit should be about 0.12 XMR/day, but I'm getting much lower profits, only about 0.04 XMR/day.

The site says that on average every 40 minutes a block is found, but I often see that the last found block was 3 or 4 hours ago.

So, whats wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the "Pool blocks" page, you can see in the last column the luck indicator, which is essentially the number of hashes produced by the pool to mine that block vs. the difficulty of the block.

They seem to just have gone through an unlucky sequence with fewer blocks found than expected.

A few notes on this:

- there will always be an element of luck in finding the next block, but over time the frequency of blocks should be close to the estimated value
- for example, at 2 MH/s vs network hashrate of 50 MH/s, they would find a block every 50 minutes on average, with a ca. 2% probability to find no block for 4h or more, and 15% for 2h
- the longer you mine, the closer you should get to your 0.12 a day
- the "faster" the pool, the quicker you will get close to your average thanks to the pool "smoothing" of large random events - but the pool you mention looks reasonably large at the moment so shouldn't be a problem
- it can never be completely ruled out that the pool is cheating: they may have changed the code of the pool to skip blocks from time to time (I'm not saying it's the case here), they could also change the luck indicator; you can (and should) look at block history and compare the average frequency over time vs their speed to get a feeling of their honesty.

Comment: On 1/23/2017 between 12:00 and 1:00 PM there have been mined 6 blocks. Since my hash rate is 1KH/s, the total hash rate of the pool is 2300 KH/s, and the block reward is 8.8 XMR, I should get: 1/2300 * 8.8 = 0.038 XMR (fees not included), but I got only about ~0.02. There must be something wrong.

Comment: Is 1KH/s the rate you see on your mining software or the hashrate you see on their website? Also their website currently shows 4 MH/s hashrate - the number of XMR you get is based on the number of hashes you submitted during the period to find the block vs. the number of hashes in the pool over the same period.

Comment: What is also interesting at moneropool.com is the fluctuating pool hash rate, going from 3 MH/s to 4.5 MH/s within 10 minutes $*#@!* The 1 KH/s rate is that of the mining software (1x Intel Core i5 = 150H/s + 1x Radeon R9 390X = 840H/s)

Comment: @maitscha it seems to be prone to pool hopping indeed...

Comment: Are there pools where pool hopping is somehow prevented?

Comment: @maitscha some pools use different algorithms to allocate XMR to miners that makes pool hopping inefficient, such as [PPLNS](http://give-me-coins.com/support/faq/what-is-pplns/). I'm not sure which pools use which algos - if they say nothing then you can assume it's PPS. Some pools also ban cloud mining services (for example supportxmr and monerohash) which is a large source of pool hopping.

Comment: So I switched now to minexmr.com, where the profits are very equal to the estimations. There is something wrong with moneropool.com, because the profits are only a half of the estimations.